# Android - Add contacts in 1.5

Tags: android, contacts, contactscontract

I'm making my application compatible with Android 1.5 (APLI level 3) from 2.3.3. The only thing I have to change (according to the compiler) is the code used to add a contact in the phonebook. The code for 2.3.3 is the following:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "Name");
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, "Email");
        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "phone");
        int PICK_CONTACT = 100;
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
```

The problem with 1.5 is that ContactsContract is not recognized. 
How can I convert this code for 1.5?

Regards.